# Shell command to delete old network users on Mac OS X Server

Tags: macos, bash, shell, osx-server

I'm trying to delete old network user accounts off our lab server (Mac OS X 10.6). I found a simple command line command to find user directories that have not been accessed for over a year:

```
find /Volumes/Server-HD2/NetworkUsers/Students -type d -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -not -name "." -mtime +356
```

Running this command successfully lists all of the old accounts. I then found what looks like a simple for loop, but it doesn't work:

```
#!/bin/bash

keep1="/Volumes/Server-HD2/NetworkUsers/Students/studenttest"
keep2="/Volumes/Server-HD2/NetworkUsers/Students/studenttest2"

USERLIST='find /Volumes/Server-HD2/NetworkUsers/Students -type d -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -not -name "." -mtime +356'

for a in $USERLIST ; do
  [[ "$a" == "$keep1" ]] && continue                    #skip account 1
  [[ "$a" == "$keep2" ]] && continue                    #skip account 2
  echo "Deleting account and home directory for" $a
  dscl . delete $a                                      #delete the account
  rm -r $a                                              #delete the home directory
done
```

When I run this command as an executable shell file or just straight in the command line, it loops through $a as being each word in the $USERLIST. In other works if I simply do this:

```
USERLIST='find /Volumes/Server-HD2/NetworkUsers/Students -type d -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -not -name "." -mtime +356'

for a in $USERLIST ; do 
   echo $a
done
```

It will return:

```
find
/Volumes/Server-HD2/NetworkUsers/Students
-type
d
-maxdepth
1
-mindepth
1
...
```

whereas I would expect it to return each directory that meets the "find" command.

I need to figure out how to make an array of the results from the find command to loop through. I guess I simply don't understand how the arrays and strings are handled in bash. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have enclosed your `find` command in the `USERLIST` assignment in single quotes – that will assign the whole command *as a string* to the `$USERLIST` variable (foregoing all shell expansion – that’s what single quotes are for). Instead, to get the command output assigned, you need to enclose it in backticks (`) or in a `$(<command>)` construct, i.e.

```
USERLIST=`find /Volumes/Server-HD2/NetworkUsers/Students -type d -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -not -name "." -mtime +356`
```

or

```
USERLIST=$(find /Volumes/Server-HD2/NetworkUsers/Students -type d -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -not -name "." -mtime +356)
```

Comment: Thanks! Maybe the original source and the backtick and it somewhere got typed or copied as a single quote (').

Comment: Backticks are confusing in several respects.  Just use `$( )` instead.